# c# clr udf scan sql table

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to create CLR UDF to scan a SQL table and read each column and sum all data for
each column (I am working with big datasets, like `>1000` columns and `20,000,000>rows`).

I'd like to compare applying for each column `SUM(COLUMN_NAME)` SQL function with parallelized `for loop`

So The SQL would look like

```
SELECT SUM(COLUMN_1),SUM(COLUMN_2),SUM(COLUMN_3),...,SUM(COLUMN_1000)
```

How can I do a `CLR UDF in C#` that would do that?

I am planning to use an array, so each time I read the row I add it like:
 `array[i]+= sqlValue;`

How to do this, so I can execute both of them in a `stored proc`?

Table

```
column_1  column_2 column_3   .... column_1000
---------------------------------------------
     451      57     253                 135
     251      77     356                 965
     481      15     323                 655  
     452      15     135                 665
    ... 
    ...20,000,000 more rows
```

Comment: How does your CLR UDF look like? What did you already try? Creating a CLR UDF is well documented.

Comment: to scan the table by column and to do the for loop in parallel? Do you have an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what you're trying to achieve is to do a thousand `SELECT column_x FROM table`, one for each column, and do the summing from hand.

That means 1000 parallel connections to the database all working within the same table within the same rows, locking each other (until you use `with nolock`).

The benefit to `SELECT sum(column_1), sum(column_2), ...`. I can't see one and I believe what you're trying will be magnitudes slower than letting SQL Server doing what it does best.

**EDIT:**

As per your request here's a quick'n'dirty sample, not tested since I currently have no SQL server at hand. I assumed the columns are of type `long` and the result is of type `decimal`.

```
public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{
    private static string GetCommandText(int column)
    {
        return string.Format("select column_{0} from table", column);
    }

    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(
        DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read,
        TableDefinition = "result decimal",
        FillRowMethodName = "FillRow",
        SystemDataAccess = SystemDataAccessKind.Read)]
    public static IEnumerable fnSum(int columnNo)
    {
        var values = new List<long>();

        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(GetCommandText(columnNo), new SqlConnection("context connection=true")))
        {
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleResult | CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    values.Add(reader.GetInt64(0));
                }
            }
        }

        return list;
    }

    private static void FillRow(object obj, out decimal result)
    {
        var values = (List<long>)obj;

        result = values.Sum(value => (decimal) value);
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe just using 4 threads, also I would like to do other complex formulas, sum is very easy, but what about, sqr or log....What I need is an example of clr udf c# to scan columns... Could you point one tutorial?

Comment: @cMinor, can't you just create your own aggregate function with [`CREATE AGGREGATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182741.aspx) and use the [mathematical functions offered by T-SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177516.aspx)?

Comment: I just confirmed that you can't (and shouldn't) spawn multiple threads within a SQL CLR function.

Comment: @VVS: the threads issue is understood....   I will try that also, but I am interested in doing via c#, how to scan by column or row?

Comment: +1, I agree with you: `magnitudes slower than letting SQL Server doing what it does best.`

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but if your "real" problem is that you need to frequently run a slow query that scans the entire table doing SUM() on each column, then the fastest and easiest way to achieve this is a persisted aggregate view.  It basically incurs the SUM() overhead on INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE but the SELECT speed is instant.

You basically make a view like:

```
CREATE VIEW MyView WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
SELECT SUM(col1) AS SumCol1, SUM(col2) AS SumCol2, ...
FROM dbo.YourTable
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX idx_MyView ON MyView(SumCol1,SumCol2)
```